# SFML texture not loading when encapsulating class member function is called from outside

Tags: c++, c++11, sfml

tl/dr:I've moved a function call from inside a class to outside a class and the function stopped working.

I've run in to the most baffeling problem in the year or so I've been working with c++. I can't find anything to explain what is happening here but to be honest I have a hard time even formulating a SEO question.

the base operation here is rather simple,

1. create a sf::Texture and sf::Sprite object
2. Load a texture to the sf::Texture object
3. set texture of sf::Sprite to the texture object
4. display the sf::Sprite

all 4 steps went fine within one function, but because my goal was to build a game engine I started encapsulating it into larger classes.

I created a GameEngine class and let it handle step 4. this went well after some corrections.

then I created a GameObject class to handle the first three steps, all I had to do then as a 'user' of the framework was create the object and tell it to render, this also worked.

Then I hit a snag when I moved the functioncall for step 2. from the constructer of the object to outside of the object.

old situation:
    class GameObject
    {
        ObjectType d_type;
        GameEngine *d_engine;

```
    sf::Texture d_texture;
    sf::Sprite d_sprite;
    bool isactive;
    public:
        GameObject(GameEngine *engine, ObjectType type);

        void addtexture(std::string textpath);

        void render();
```

and

```
GameObject::GameObject(GameEngine *engine, ObjectType type)
:
    d_type(type),
    d_engine(engine),
    d_texture(),
    d_sprite(),
isactive{false}
{
    addtexture("textures//MenuBackGround.png"); //<- problematic line
    d_sprite.setTexture(d_texture);
}

void GameObject::addtexture(std::string textpath)
{
    if(!d_texture.loadFromFile(textpath))
    {
        cout << "couldn't load texture in\n";
    } else
    {
        cout << "did load texture\n";
    }
}
```

this works and I see the texture I created apear in the window. If I now create a class Loadingscreen:

```
class Loading_Screen : public Base_State
{
    std::vector<GameObject> d_backgrounds;

    public:
        Loading_Screen(GameEngine *engine);
        virtual ~Loading_Screen();
```

with implementation:

```
Loading_Screen::Loading_Screen(GameEngine *engine)
{
    GameObject temp(engine, ObjectType::BACKGROUND);
    d_backgrounds.push_back(temp);
    temp.addtexture("textures//MenuBackGround.png");
}
```

I only see a blackscreen. but in both cases I get the message that the texture was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're actually rendering d_backgrounds, I **think** the error is here:

```
Loading_Screen::Loading_Screen(GameEngine *engine)
{
    GameObject temp(engine, ObjectType::BACKGROUND);
    d_backgrounds.push_back(temp);
    temp.addtexture("textures//MenuBackGround.png");
}
```

You are creating a `GameObject` object. Then you insert *a copy of it* into the container, and what you're trying to `addtexture` later is not the same object you inserted.

Try this:

```
Loading_Screen::Loading_Screen(GameEngine *engine)
{
    GameObject temp(engine, ObjectType::BACKGROUND);
    temp.addtexture("textures//MenuBackGround.png");
    d_backgrounds.push_back(temp);
}
```

Looking at SFML api, `Texture` and `Sprite` have both proper copy constructors, so it should be fine this way.

Comment: no that didn't work, in the mean time I was playing around with it myself and tried to make d_backgrounds a vector of pointers this sadly didn't solve the problem. and like I said the only thing that I have to change to go from working to not working is change where the addtexture function is called from, rendering is done the sameway in both cases.

Comment: That was wrong anyway. You were passing a copy of the object without the texture being initialised. When trying to use pointers, did you add the objects like this? 
    GameObject* tmp = new GameObject(...);
    temp->addtexture(...);
    d_backgrounds.push_back(temp); I don't currently have SFML api in mind, but probably something is messing with the sprite and the texture being both objects and copy constructor.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the sf::Texture and sf::Sprite to be held as pointers by the GameObject thereby removing any copying that could happen when the GameObject is handled. thanks for your time.